# Sending a mail with php: Script is waiting for the answer?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using the class [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/PHPMailer?tm=6) to send Mails via SMTP:

```
   <?php 
require 'php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.dfgdfgdfg.de';              // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'dfgdfg';                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'dfgsdfgdsfg';                           // SMTP password
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->From = 'community@fdgdfg.de';
    $mail->FromName = 'dfgdfgdg';
    $mail->AddAddress('interview@dfgdfg.de', 'Udo');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'HTML-Mail mit Logo';
    $mail->Body    = 'Nachfolgend das <b>Logo</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Aktiviere HTML, damit das Logo angezeigt wird';

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

?>
```

My Questions:

1. Whats the best way to send to a lot of Mails (same Mailtext, only the appellation is different (Hello $NAME)?
2. Is the PHP script waiting until every mail is delivered? Because sometimes I want to send a mail to some hundreds people, when a user is doing an action on the website. so this user cant wait of course, until all those mail were sent succesful!

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Two things to try: First, are you running this locally and/or behind a firewall? I recently had an issue where testing a sendmail PHP script behind a firewall resulted in "endless connections". And secondly - would it work for your purposes to run multiple threads to send out a large number of messages?

Comment: sending mails take little time but when u send loads of them it can take a while.

Comment: The script runs at a normally webserver. No, i dont want to use multiple threads, because i dont know how to ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting PHPMailer to interact with SMTP, so I guess that it will wait for it to complete. This is not optimal, because as you say you will block the PHP script until SMTP responds.

It would be better to send through your localhost: set PHPMailer to use sendmail, which will usually be a wrapper to a local exim4 or postfix, which will then handle the mailing for you. This is much better, also because the local server will handle any possible temporary error, and retry later. PHP won't.

You may also want to explore other options, like Mandrill or Sendgrid to do the job, especially if you do lot of mailing or bulk mailing.

Comment: What do u mean with localhost? The script is at a webserver...sendmail is not using the php mail()-function, it is? When i use sendmail, should i send the mails in a loop or with BBC? I heard BBC is dangerous, because some provider could mark your mails as spam...

Comment: If you use mail(), then PHP will mail through the method defined in php.ini. This method is usually sendmail, and sendmail in turn is a local wrapper that invokes the mailserver of your ISP. If you do not manage your server, this is probably the most reliable way.

Comment: For the BCC, if you mail a lot and want to avoid spam, then you should definitely take a look at sendgrid or mandrill. Both have a free plan.

Answer (score 1):

> Whats the best way to send to a lot of Mails (same Mailtext, only the
>   appellation is different (Hello $NAME)?

You can do something like, Set the name too.

```
// rest of code first
$mail->AddAddress("you@example.com")

$ids = mysql_query($select, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($ids)) {
  $mail->AddBCC($row[0]);
}

$mail->Send();//Sends the email
```

You can have special string 'name_here' in the body and place `$name` with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

```
Is the PHP script waiting until every mail is delivered? Because sometimes I want to send a mail to some hundreds people, when a user is doing an action on the website. so this user cant wait of course, until all those mail were sent succesful!
```

Yes according to my knowledge you will have to wait.

How to do a str_replace ? Assume that your email body is as follows

```
$body = " Dear %first_name%,

other stuff goes here....... ";

$body = str_replace("%first_name%", $first_name, $body);
```

above will replace %first_name% with the name($first_name) you provide.

Comment: 1. Question: What makes "MsgHTML()"? 2. where to user str_replace? generating a new mailtext for every user and then send the mail in a loop?

Comment: str_replace is used to replace the name_here text with the $name

Comment: yes of course, but WHERE in the script i should use str_replace? in your example I send to every user a mail with ONE text. do u know what i mean?